# JsPlumb connect not using existing source/target endpoint style

Tags: javascript, html, jsplumb

Firstly, there are two nodes in the canvas, and some endpoint styles has been applied. If I drag a connection between them, all styles can be kept. That's OK.
But when using jsPlumb connection method, it will import default endpoint style rather than the given styles. How can I avoid this?

1) new connection generated by user drag event from source to target.
[image]

2) using jsplumb.connect(), while the method using default endpoint styles.
[image]

some javascript code is here:

```
    var connectorPaintStyle = {
        strokeWidth: 2,
        stroke: "#61B7CF",
        joinstyle: "round",
        outlineStroke: "white",
        outlineWidth: 2
    };

    var conn = jsptoolkit.jspinstance.connect({
        source: line.sdata.sourceId,
        target: line.sdata.targetId,
        anchors: line.sdata.anchors,
        paintStyle: connectorPaintStyle,
        connector: ["Flowchart", { stub: [2, 2], gap: 1, cornerRadius: 5, alwaysRespectStubs: true }],
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to use uuids array rather than source and target. I have modified the connect method code:

```
var conn = jsptoolkit.jspinstance.connect({
        uuids: [line.sdata.sourceId + "RightMiddle", line.sdata.targetId + "LeftMiddle"],
        anchors: line.sdata.anchors,
    });
```

There is a similar question:
[Jsplumb add connection programatically using endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606106/jsplumb-add-connection-programatically-using-endpoints)